# "The object that is sent the message is called the target"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Grammar check. Native speaker's opinion needed.

The sentence "The object that is sent the message is called the target" seems incomplete at best. Could a native English speaker confirm this?

It is hard to know what is meant

A bit confused here.

Comment: it is NONE OF 1,2,3,4.  **The object that GETS the message**, is called the target.

Comment: The sentence is not incomplete, it uses the passive voice and has the correct meaning.  However, I would reword it exactly as FumbleFingers does, because the current version is possible to misunderstand if reading too quickly.

Comment: Fumble's version is miserable for a different reason — *one desperately needs the everyday word "received" to express this simple concept clearly*. There's no need to torturously rework the given sentence, avoiding *received*. Furthermore, if anyone cares this much about OO, probably *directed* is technically safer than *sent* in the alternate version. *Sent* rather suggests completion of the process. The target is: what it's addressed to, directed to, where you want it to go. (Likely, it has not yet been sent anywhere — and if it has, you'd talk naturally of it having been *received*.)

Comment: @Joe Blow: Don't fly off the handle, but can we stick to discussing grammar and semantics, not programming?

Comment: @Fumb Hmm, for sure, but note that everything I say in the above comment would apply to any situation where the sentence is used. (A discussion of archery, or mail-handling, say.) You can see that *received* desperately needs to be used, and *sent* has the "it has already happened, too complete" problem: something like *directed* or *addressed to* is needed. Straightforward.

Comment: @mac: Thank you for that edit! The EL&U system has just started nagging me because I haven't upvoted many *questions* lately, so your edit gave me the perfect excuse to upvote yours!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically speaking I think it would be hard to dispute the grammar of this sentence, but it's stylistically appalling, and would probably never be used.

A normal English version would be...

**The object to which the message is sent is called the target.**

In order to get away from the "programmers reference guide" associations of the original sentence, consider

**The person who is sent the letter is called the addressee** (poor phrasing)

**The person to whom the letter is sent is called the addressee** (better)

**The addressee is the person to whom the letter is sent** (even better)

**The addressee is the person the letter is sent to** (best, in my opinion)

Comment: I agree completely. Was very surprised to see sentence posted above in a published book

Comment: "would probably never be used" - I wish I were as optimistic about the state of technical literature :-)

Comment: "The object the message is sent to is called the target." Would it be another way to put it? I have a feeling it sounds natural, but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano: Yes, your alternative is fine. Personally I don't like having the two **is**'s so close together, which is why I forced a greater separation in my final 'non-programming' alternative. Others may not care about that, but we all have our stylistic preferences.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Thanks for your comment. I understand what you mean about stylistic preferences. I like your better and best alternatives, although over the years I've somehow learnt to avoid constructs such as "to whom" because I've read and heard that they sound stilted (albeit perfectly fine from a grammatical standpoint).

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano: Okay, I'll come clean. My "bestest" version would be **The addressee is the person the letter is sent to**, and damn all those who say I can't end a sentence with a preposition! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers. As long as that's something up with which you will put ;)

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano: Sadly, I think the great man never actually said it, but we're both up on our pseudo-Churchill... http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/churchill.html

Comment: @JuanPabloCalifano let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/700/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-juan-pablo-califano)

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, for example in a computer manual, you may want something like this:

> If a message is sent from *A* to *B*, then *A* is called the **source** and *B* is called the **target**.

Maybe, if other terminology is needed, you would go on like this:

> We say that *A* **emits** the message and *B* **receives** the message.

Or whatever teminology you want to specify.

Answer (score -1):

As a professional technical writer, I can see potential confusion around the phrase *is sent*. I would be inclined to rephrase it as:

> The object that receives the message is called the target.

Many of the other sentences offered here work too, but they don't remove the ambiguity entirely, and the phrasing is clunky in many of them.

I've done quite a lot of technical writing that refers to messaging, and it's best to very clearly delineate the process as:

> Message sent by a sender -> Message transmitted by a process -> Messsage received by a receiver

If you start trying to mix the terms sending/transmission/receiving then it just gets complicated.

Comment: As an (ex-) professional *software* writer, I also like to be precise. Just because a message is *sent*, doesn't mean it will ever be received. I would take issue with any technical writer who rephrased *my* "draft technical spec" text in that way, because sometimes the finer nuances of what was being said might get lost in a well-meaning attempt to describe what someone *thought* I meant.

Comment: Ah, OK, I can see the nuance. What about "The object expected to receive the message is called the target"?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't have any problem with that semantically. Nor with the 3-part definition of the messaging process in your answer. In the final analysis I imagine you're right that *as a technical writer* you don't endorse using a verb relevant to one part of the process to define a component within another part. A bit like mixing metaphors, I guess. But in this case we're really talking about acceptable usage re OP's definition - it seems odd to recast it to suit other definitions *he may not be concerned with*.

Comment: Fair enough. A tech writer's role is to bring clarity, and sometimes that means being particularly anal with definitions. It's a constant struggle to ensure we're using clear and simple language without changing the nuance of the original (sometimes very convoluted) sentence. As for the OPs definition, well he didn't give much of one ;)

Comment: I think the issue in hand here is very finely nuanced, but really your concern is the *preferred style* in the very specific case of technical write-ups about **messaging** (presumably in an IT context). Which would maybe suit better at *writers.se*. I tried to deal with the fact that OP's sentence, while valid, was really stretching the use of "sent" beyond acceptable limits in *any* context.